# Django increases image size in byte while resizing it

Tags: python, django, image

The scenario is, client uploads a image to my Django service, and the Django service needs to resize the image dimension to be `600 x 600`, and the image size in bytes should be reduced.

Here's the code I used:

```
import StringIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
image.thumbnail((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

However, I found it sometimes will even increase the image size in bytes. Sometimes the client uploads a image with dimension `1000 x 1000` and size `80kb`, after execute the above line to generate thumbnail, the thumbnail is `600 x 600` with size `130kb`. I am expecting something like `50kb` (at least less than `80kb` after compress)

please help

Comment: Try messing with the [JPEG writer's options](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg), maybe lowering the quality or optimizing will help?

Answer (score 1):

try with this, may be this method help you.

```
import StringIO
from PIL import Image

image_field = self.cleaned_data.get('image_field')
image_file = StringIO.StringIO(image_field.read())
image = Image.open(image_file)
w, h0 = image.size

image = image.resize((w/2, h/2), Image.ANTIALIAS)

image_file = StringIO.StringIO()
image.save(image_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)

image_field.file = image_file
```